# Django models compare field to field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Let's say we have model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    int_field_one = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    int_field_two = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The question is: 
Does Django models supports filter one field by another field? 
In other words i want to exectute following query

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE int_field_one > int_field_two
```

with filter syntax `MyModel.objects.filter(int_field_one=int_field_two)`

Answer (score 5):

You need [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) and the `__gt` [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-reference):

`MyModel.objects.filter(int_field_one__gt=F('int_field_two'))`

Comment: Yep, it works. Thank you!